# Combining instanced pallets w/ non-instanced pallets

Tags: pallet, runtime, loose-coupling, tight-coupling

## Overview

We have a system that leverages both instanced pallets and non-instanced pallets. Specifically, we have pallets that maintain on-chain merkle trees. We can have many instances of these pallets, a la `::<T: Config<I>, I: 'static>` type trait definitions.

The questions we have particularly relate to tightly coupling instanced pallets with non-instanced pallets, i.e. a pallet with just `::<T: Config>` implementations.

### Broken Non-instanced pallet Config

Currently, the non-instanced pallet `Config` needs to provide some instance to instantiate the tight coupling between the instanced pallet as follows. However, the non-instanced pallet has no notion of instances `I` so this of course doesn't compile. The traits in question are implemented with instances and so do not work in this environment.

```rust
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_balances::Config {
    ...

    /// VAnchor Interface
    type VAnchor: VAnchorInterface<VAnchorConfigration<Self, I>>
        + VAnchorInspector<VAnchorConfigration<Self, I>>;

}
```

### Ideal Non-instanced pallet Config

The ideal case would be to have a new trait that somehow encompasses an individual instance of the instanced pallet while not restricting it to `Instance1` or `Instance2` even if that would be possible. What we have in mind is something such as:

```rust
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_balances::Config {
    ...

    /// VAnchor Interface
    type VAnchor: VAnchorInterface<VAnchorConfigrationInstance<Self>>
        + VAnchorInspector<VAnchorConfigrationInstance<Self>>;

}
```

However we are unsure how to massage these into reality.

### Runtime Implementation

The goal for our runtime is to provide something akin to the following:

```rust
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = opaque::Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic
    {
        ...
        // VAnchor
        VAnchorBn254: pallet_vanchor::<Instance1>::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>},
        VAnchorBls381: pallet_vanchor::<Instance2>::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>},
        PalletInQuestion: pallet_in_question::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Config<T>},
    }
);

impl pallet_in_question::Config for Runtime {
    VAnchor = VAnchorBn254
}
```

#### Questions

1. Is this doable and sensible?
2. Are there examples or design patterns for this.
3. How to work around the lack of instancing in the non-instanced pallet?

Comment: Why does the `VAnchorInterface` trait depend on the instance of the implementing pallet? Sure you can inject an instance into your pallets config like `type VaInstance: 'static;` but it seems odd to me. Could you post the full code please? Tight coupling normally means to directly call into another pallet and bypass any config to configure which or how.

Comment: This PR contained the work leading to this question. We opted to keep everything instanced to continue pushing this work forward: https://github.com/webb-tools/protocol-substrate/pull/303